# Provide injection holomorphic such, that $ \varphi(U)=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Re} z>0, \operatorname{Im} z>0\} $

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

> Let $U=B(1+i, \sqrt{2}) \cap B(1-i, \sqrt{2}) .$ Please provide
>    injection holomorphic function $\varphi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
>    such, that $$ \varphi(U)=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Re} z>0,
>  \operatorname{Im} z>0\} $$ (we have infinitely many of this function
>    compute only one).

I am a bit confusing. I tried compute the Möbius transformation.

$f(z)=\frac{a z+b}{c z+d}$

$\varphi(0) = 0 = =\frac{b}{d} = 0 \iff b = 0$

$\varphi(1) = \frac{a}{c+d} = \infty \iff c+d = 0 \iff c = -d$

But I have problem with the second points, because we have collinear points.

It's good direction of solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given region $U$ is bounded by two circular arcs which terminate at $0$ and $2$ in the complex plane. Suppose we choose a Mobius transformation $$f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$ sending $f(0) = 0$ and $f(2) = \infty$. This implies $b = 0$ and $2c+d = 0$, so all such Mobius transformations are of the form $$f(z) = \frac{\lambda z}{z-2}$$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Finally, choose $\lambda$ so that $f(1)=-\lambda$ is in the first quadrant, with $\text{Re}(z) > 0$ and $\text{Im}(z) > 0$, e.g. by taking $\lambda = -(1+i)$.

Note that $U$ can be exhausted by circular arcs joining $0$ and $2$ (corresponding to circles through $0$ with center on the line $\text{Re}(z) = 1$). Our map $f$ sends each of these circles to a ray emanating from $0$. For example, it sends the "circular arc" $\text{Im}(z) = 0$ to the ray $\text{Re}(z) = \text{Im}(z)$ (i.e., the part of this line in the first quadrant).

Where does $f$ send $$\partial U = \{\text{Arc containing $1+i$}\} \cup \{\text{Arc containing $1-i$}\}?$$ We can calculate $f(1+i) = -1+i$ and $f(1-i) = 1-i$ to see that $f$ sends $\partial U$ to the line $\text{Re}(z) = -\text{Im}(z)$, sending the top arc to the ray in the second quadrant and the bottom arc to the ray in the fourth quadrant. We conclude that $f$ sends $U$ biholomorphically to a half-plane.

We can now post-compose with a rotation to make this image the upper half-plane, and then a (suitable branch of the) square root map to make it the first quadrant, as desired. More precisely, let $g(z) = e^{2\pi i/8} z$ and $h(z) = \sqrt{z}$, taking the standard branch with cut along the positive real axis. Then, $h \circ g \circ f$ is a biholomorphism from $U$ to $\{z\in \mathbb{C} \, : \, \text{Re}(z) > 0 \text{ and } \text{Im}(z) > 0\}$.

Comment: Thanks, many good